# How to make C's fopen function search or create a file in a specific directory?

Tags: c, file, directory, compilation, fopen

When I call the function fopen to create or read a file in a specific directory, it does not work.

If I call the function to read or create the file in the root project, it works very well.

This is my folder structure:

```
|--project/
|--main.c
|--files/
```

if I call the function in this way:

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("project/files/test.txt", "w");
```

It does not work. The function cannot create the file;

But if i call in this whay, it works:

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("test.txt", "w");
```

Whay? And how can I do this?

Comment: "The function cannot create the file;" ===> Does the function return `NULL`? Does calling `perror()` print anything meaningful?

Comment: The relative path in your `fopen()` call requires `project` to be an existing subdirectory of the current working directory, `files` to be an existing subdirectory of that, both of those to be readable and traversible by the program, and the latter to be writable by the program.  There could be other requirements as well, but if that `fopen()` call is failing then most likely it is one of those conditions that is not satisfied.

Comment: Where's your code?  Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to know how to post questions.  There are ways to know yourself what is happening (in your case you cannot create a file in a non-existent directory, is the most probable thing happening)

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` does not create directories.

Your directory structure is:

```
root/
|--project/
|--main.c
|--files/
```

`"files"` files in not a subdirectory of the `"project"` directory

(I assume that the program is run from the `root` directory)